# How to switch to another Teams tab calling button onclick JS/TypeScript

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am programming app with more MS Teams tabs. In first tab i have button, which should lead to switch to other Teams tab.

In TeamsToolkit I made second tab with onclick on

[image]

I'm trying to call pages.tabs.navigateToTab function:

const doClick = (evt: React.MouseEvent) => {
const tabInstance: TabInstance = {
entityId: "index0", tabName: "Personal Tab", url: "index.html#/tab", websiteUrl:       "https://localhost:53000/index.html#/tab"
};
pages.tabs.navigateToTab(tabInstance);
}

but only content changes, I miss change in "selected" item in top menu:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it even possible to manipulate "selected" item in tab list?

Answer (score 0):

Another tab is another application basically (maybe not even yours, like "Files" for example or "Posts" tab). You can tell teams to activate another tab using so-called "deep links". I am not sure, how to do it with teams tookit, but with teams API you just call `executeDeepLink` (v1) or `pages.navigateToApp` (v2) with corresponding link.

Read more about deep links here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

Comment: Thank You, deep link works well for my case.